# Скрипт счетчика работает криво

Tags: javascript

Собственно сам скрипт. Работает, нареканий сначала не возникало, но когда счетчик доходит до 0, он соответственно уходит в `-`.
У меня есть обработчик этого, но он не работает. Решил вывести значения переменных в консоль и что вижу `- число число число`. 
То есть не все числа уходят в минут. можно как-то исправить?

```
offset = 60 * 60 * 0.03;
id = 'time';

function update() {
  u = parseInt(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
  time = getCookie('time');
  if (!time) {
    time = u + offset;
    setCookie('time', time);
  }
  today = u;
  day = (today - time) / 86400 * -1;
  days = Math.floor(day);
  clock = Math.floor((day - days) * 24);
  min = Math.floor((((day - days) * 24) - clock) * 60);
  console.log(days);
  console.log(clock);
  console.log(min);
  if (days <= 0 && clock <= 0 && min <= 0) {
    document.getElementById('header-get_precent').innerHTML = '0 дней 0 часов 0 минут конец';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('header-get_precent').innerHTML = days + ' дней ' + clock + ' часов ' + min + ' минут';
  }
}
setTimeout(update, 500);

function getCookie(name) {
  var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
    "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"
  ));
  return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
}

function setCookie(name, value, options) {
  options = options || {};
  var expires = options.expires;
  if (typeof expires == "number" && expires) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + expires * 1000);
    expires = options.expires = d;
  }
  if (expires && expires.toUTCString) {
    options.expires = expires.toUTCString();
  }
  value = encodeURIComponent(value);
  var updatedCookie = name + "=" + value;
  for (var propName in options) {
    updatedCookie += "; " + propName;
    var propValue = options[propName];
    if (propValue !== true) {
      updatedCookie += "=" + propValue;
    }
  }
  document.cookie = updatedCookie;
}
```

Comment: В примере должен быть код, а не фото...

Comment: Прикрепил свой код

Comment: @Air я понимаю "с началом", "с начала" и "сначала". Но вот "с начало" - нет. Это как?

Comment: С начала* Могли бы и помочь, а не на грамматику внимание свое переводить.

Comment: вы бы тоже могли отнестись к сообществу уважительнее: [прочитать справку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), оформить вопрос в соотвествии с рекомендациями, подумать как продемонстрировать нам проблему явно, убрать ненужные для разбора getCookie и setCookie :)

Comment: @norbornen в таких случаях, кстати, хорошо подходит ссылка [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: а вообще всё просто: нужно проверять не `days <= 0 && clock <= 0 && min <= 0`, а `if (days >= 0 && clock >= 0 && min >= 0) { 'не конец' } esle { 'конец' }`

Comment: @YanGrinberg как у вас запускается счетчик на самом деле? `setTimeout` отрабатывает ровно один раз. Как выглядит "У меня есть обработчик этого"? Надеюсь, это не `days <= 0 && clock <= 0 && min <= 0`, который сломается при отрицательном значении, ибо `min` станет положительным? При достижении нуля/отрицательной разницы между датами лучше сразу прекращать работу счетчика, а не рассчитывать на часы и минуты, как-то посчитанные для отрицательного значения

Comment: @YanGrinberg, ну да `о`  в конце не заметил... Да и в данном случае пишется  слитно...